# Why use transactions to call contracts?

Tags: transactions, contract

The transaction operation can be used to transfer tez, but also to call a smart contract. This leads to security issues since a user may be tricked into calling a contract when she simply wanted to transfer money.

What's the rationale of using the same operation for two quite different purposes?

Comment: could you expand on the "security issue" ? i am not sure i understand what you have in mind

Comment: I was referring to the anti-pattern "refunding to a list of contract" https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/tutorials/michelson_anti_patterns.html

Comment: The list of anti-patterns are now found here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/michelson_anti_patterns.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand the concepts, transferring tezos is one kind of contract. It has amount to move from account to another and the move is containing a transaction to track, that the operation gets through in meaningful time. So, actually tezos transfer is a small contract, sort of.

What about smart contract data types (is it amount of money in tezos, dollars, changing car to newer + some money,...) the options are unlimited, unless the Michelson language is and other blockchain rules are obeyed. Baking is the thing that makes it secure and I don't believe the type of data is in any role there.